# Is it possible to implement a Mutex with atomic instructions?

Tags: concurrency, atomic, compare-and-swap

I presume when a thread acquires a lock it needs a to compare-exchange a variable indicating it had entered a critical section.

That leads me to believe implanting mutex needs support of atomic instructions like compare exchange.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Some kind of atomicity is necessary, but not sufficient (well, it may be enough for a spinlock but not a fully-featued mutex). Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Depends on your understanding of “atomic instructions” and whether you’re talking about SMP machines or just preemptive multitasking, etc. There are solutions for systems without atomic cas, as long as certain ordering guarantees can be made. Surely, no hardware vendor would construct a CPU with parallel processing support without any operation that could control it.

Comment: Is it fair to conclude then the cost of a uncontended mutex MUST always be greater than the atomic increment?

Comment: The uncontended case of a mutex can be implemented as a single atomic instruction in the best case. Which means, acquiring it, performing the actual increment instruction, followed by releasing it, makes three CPU instructions in the best case, which likely is slightly slower than a single atomic increment instruction without a mutex. It’s not a factor three, though. Further, when using a programing language’s built-in mutex, the compiler may identify adjacent uses of the same mutex and optimize it. What really makes a difference, is the contended case.